# How can I post a JSON multi-dimensional data via Jquery.post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

How can I post a JSON multi-dimensional data via $.post? For instance, I have this multi-dimensional array in JSON format:

```
{
    "file":
    {
       "name" : "1024x768.jpg",
       "type" : "image\/jpeg",
       "tmp_name" : "C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php8F59.tmp",
       "error":0,"size":469159
    }
}
```

I will use `Jquery.post()` to post the JSON data.

```
$.post("process.php",'{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php8F59.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}}',function(xml){

});
```

So I can get this array in `process.php` using `print_r($_POST)`:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1024x768.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpA1.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 469159
        )
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `$.post(//stuff here, data: $(yourArray).serialize());`, maybe?

Comment: what kind of data I should prepare for `$(yourArray)`? thanks.

Comment: It can be an array or a bunch of objects using jQuery selectors; both are arrays of data and `.serialize()` will find all `:input` elements, or serialize the whole lot if it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.post("process.php",{"file":{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php8F59.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}},function(xml){

});
```

that should give you the desired array on the php side

Edit: this works since jQuery 1.4 and above

Comment: yes I got the data I want in php. but the json data I get is a `string` - how can I convert a string to a json?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I got another problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277821/jquey-how-can-i-combine-can-post-two-json-data-objects

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonArray ='{"file":{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php8F59.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}}';
$arr = JSON.stringify($jsonArray);

$.post("/url",{data:$arr},function(){

});
```

in the php file do

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['data']);
print_r($json);
```

*Edit*

may be this will help, i have not tested it though...

```
var file=[];
file["name"]="1024x768.jpg";
file["type"]="image/jpeg";
file["tmp_name"]="C:\wamp\tmp\phpA1.tmp";
file["error"]="0";
file["size"]="469159";


var myObject = new Object();
var enumm=["name","type","tmp_name","error","size"];

function getEnum(index){
    return enumm[index];
}


$.each(file,function(i,j){
myObject[getEnum(i)]=file[getEnum(i)];
});


$.post("/url",{data:$.param(myObject)},function(xml){

});
```

on the php side do

```
$json = parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: thanks. I will get this json data `{"file":{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php8F59.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}}` back which is not I am after sorry.