# Jquery: How can I combine two json data objects and post them?

Tags: php, json, jquery

Following on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277434/how-can-i-post-a-json-multi-dimensional-data-via-jquery-post), I have another problem - how can I combine two json data objects?

first json object,

```
{"file":{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php2C2E.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}}
```

second json object,

```
{"title":"title","content":"bla bla blah"}



$.post("process.php", first + second ,function(xml){

});
```

So I can get this array in process.php using `print_r($_POST)`:

```
Array
(

[file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1024x768.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpA1.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 469159
        )

    [title] => title
    [content] => bla bla blah
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your first data object `file` is not an array as you are expecting it in the server side `php` code. It is a `JSON` object. Anyways you can try this to combine the data objects and post it.

```
var data1 = {"file":{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php2C2E.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}};
var data2 = {"title":"title","content":"bla bla blah"}

var data = data1;
data.title = data2.title;
data.content = data2.content;

$.post("process.php", data ,function(xml){

});
```

Alternatively you can use `jQuery.extend` method which merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

```
var data1 = {"file":{"name":"1024x768.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\php2C2E.tmp","error":0,"size":469159}};
var data2 = {"title":"title","content":"bla bla blah"}

$.post("process.php", $.extend({}, data1, data2) ,function(xml){

});
```

Comment: A JSON object maps to an associative array in PHP.

Comment: thanks but it is not dynamic enough though when I have lots of data in `var data2`...

Comment: this is exactly what @Joseph Silber wrote, he should be awarded

Comment: @WooDzu - May be when I was adding the alternative solution Joseph might have provided the solution but. It was hardly difference of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.post("process.php", $.extend(true, first, second) ,function(xml){

});
```