# post json array via jquery.post?

Tags: php, json, jquery

After a series of [attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277821/jquery-how-can-i-combine-two-json-data-objects-and-post-them) working on json, now I have another challenge - How can post this type of json array,

```
[{"success":true,"filename":"agard.jpg"}]
```

jquery.post,

```
$.post("process.php", json ,function(xml){

});
```

So I can get this array in process.php using `print_r($_POST)`:

```
Array
(

    [success] => true
    [filename] => agard.jpg
)
```

Comment: The code you've shown should give you exactly the expected results

Comment: $.post("process.php", json[0] ,function(xml){ ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object not an array, you can put the array in your object though.

```
{"0":[{"success":true,"filename":"agard.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with jQuery, $.post('someUrl',[{id:'objec1'},{{id:'object2'}]). But the same does work when I try ajax posting with a REST browser plugin. I also tried explicitly stating content type: $.post('someUrl',[...], function(x){}, 'json'). It still didn't work. But I am pretty sure there is a way to send an array of json objects without having to change anything on the server side which is expecting an array.

Comment: $.ajax({url:'user.data',data:'{"symbol1":"FAKE"}',contentType:'application/json',type:'post',dataType:'json'}) worked! I tried with nodejs server. It's parser however seems to like double quotes instead of single quotes in **data**