# Post JS data to page B

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use this piece of JS:

```
$.get( "/upload/number.php", function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });
```

This makes a call to number.php, wich returns a number. In the script above i alert the data to check if this works, and it does. In the alert i see the number.

Now i wanna send this number to another page, i tried it this way:

```
$('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {
    'number'      : +data
};
```

This is not working, firebug says:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list


'number' : data
```

How can i make this work?

The complete script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // Initialiseer uploadifive
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'              : false,
        'checkScript'       : '/uploadifive/Sample/check-exists.php',
        'onFallback'        : function () {
                                  window.location = '/home.php';
                              },
        'method'            : 'POST',
        'queueID'           : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'      : '/upload/uploadifive.php',
        'removeCompleted' : true,
        'onUploadComplete'  : function (file, data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                              }
    });
     // Hang een click-event aan de knop
    $('#subby').on('click', function () {

    $.get( "/upload/number.php", function( data ) {

        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );

        });


        // Werk formData van uploadifive bij met de betreffende waarden
        $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {

            'number'      : data

        };
        // Voer de upload uit
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem (merging arrays), you have several problems. First is the scope, since `data` is not global. Then you can [merge the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277867/938236) or set the scope of your variable higher:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // Initialiseer uploadifive
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'              : false,
        'checkScript'       : '/uploadifive/Sample/check-exists.php',
        'onFallback'        : function () {
                                  window.location = '/home.php';
                              },
        'method'            : 'POST',
        'queueID'           : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'      : '/upload/uploadifive.php',
        'removeCompleted' : true,
        'onUploadComplete'  : function (file, data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                              }
    });
     // Hang een click-event aan de knop
    $('#subby').on('click', function () {   
        $.get( "/upload/number.php", function( returnednumber ) {
            // Werk formData van uploadifive bij met de betreffende waarden
            $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {  
                'number': returnednumber
                };
            });

            // Voer de upload uit
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: In your example i gonna post the data with $.post("/url/to/post", $.extend({}, formdata, number));

But Uploadifive does already sent the data after    $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');

is there another option?

Comment: I don't completely undestand your code tbh, I don't see where it gets posted again. But yes, there's another method, you can set your variable higher in the code and assign it if I'm not mistaken. Updated code.

Comment: Ok, that works, only one problem:

The number in var returnednumber has to change everytime the uploadbutton is clicked..
Now the var is only filled once with the code.
How can i change this?

Comment: Okay, try it now. I'm setting the `uploadifive()` as a callback of the `$.get()`. This means that it will only execute after the request is received. The problem before was that it sent both requests at the same time, so the second one had the old value of the first one.